# Как менять количество точек картинки (resolution)?

Tags: php, изображения, печать, imagick, dpi

Имеется папка с 3000 картинками в PNG.
У них `Pixels/Inch`: 72 и размеры 354px на 130px
На выходе нужно получить эти же картинки с `Pixels/Inch` = 300, размеры сохранить.

- Вопрос в том как эту операцию сделать хотябы для одной картинки?
- И реально ли это сделать в PHP?

PNG - не обязателен, можно и любой другой формат получить на выходе.

Comment: Для чего? Если нет цели картинки печатать, то этот параметр ни на что не влияет. Да и если печатать, то чаще всего тоже.

Comment: Именно для печати и нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('convert -units PixelsPerInch originalImage -resample 300 outputIamge');
```

Автор: [Alexey Mezenin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin).

Взял [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529385/change-dpi-of-image-from-72-to-300-using-intervention).